# Posting base64 Image from Android to Azure Mobile Backend

Tags: android, rest, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-mobile-services

I'm trying to upload a photo from my Android Client to my Mobile Backend by encoding the image in base64 and sending it through the POST body of my client app. The photo doesnt get uploaded to the server.

**My backend's method:**

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("api/addactivity")]
        public IHttpActionResult AddNewMediaActivity([FromBody]string base64String, string caption, string email, string type)
        {
            byte[] f = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
            CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            // Retrieve a reference to a container. 

            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("photos");

            // Create the container if it doesn't already exist.
            container.CreateIfNotExists();

            container.SetPermissions(
             new BlobContainerPermissions
             {
                 PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob
             });


            string uniqueBlobName = string.Format("photos" + "/" + "photos"+ "_{0}{1}", new Random().Next(1, 999999), new Random().Next(1, 999999));

            // Retrieve reference to a blob named "myblob".
            CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(uniqueBlobName);

            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(f))
            {
                blockBlob.UploadFromStream(stream);
            }
}
```

**My Android Code:**

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.getPath(),
                        options);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.URL_SAFE);

HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://mymobilewebaddress.azure-mobile.net/api/addactivity");

      try {
            // Request parameters and other properties.
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Content-Type", "application/json"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ACCEPT", "application/json"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("X-ZUMO-APPLICATION", mobileServiceAppId));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("base64String",image));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("caption",caption));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email",email));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type",type));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8"));

            //Execute and get the response.
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            if (entity != null) {
                InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                try {
                    // do something useful
                } finally {
                    instream.close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
```

However this does not upload the photo to my backend. There's no error either. The photo simply does not make it to the backend.

Am I sending the base64 string correctly via the POST?
 What am I doing wrong guys?

Comment: hey..brother ..azure has not provided an official tutorial on blob storage for android ... i already requested them to do so....see this conversation....https://disqus.com/home/inbox/replies/  .anyway from where did you get this code.

Comment: @kumarkundan This method works btw. All you need to do is send the Base64 through the POST request body instead of the URL and it will work. And as for your second question, yes I fixed it. I'll post the working code in that question now.

Comment: @kumarkundan Posted the solution mate

Comment: hey brother ... i think you need to see this https://github.com/Azure/mobile-services-samples/tree/master/CordovaUploadImages

Comment: Hey man thanks for that but what's cordova? @kumarkundan

Comment: google it bro.... and let me know if you did it ... i m also on it.. i m sure...that this one is for android ... see READ ME

Comment: take a look http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.3.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html

Comment: @kumarkundan whats ur skype username? I'm still trying to implement the image upload feature. maybe we can discuss and do it

Comment: sorry for late rply. my gmail is kkajnabi.kumar@gmail.com come to g-talk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uploading a pic to BLOB storage . I got it after searching for hours .Take a look :-

Uploading the photo image is a multistep process:

First you take a photo, and insert a TodoItem row into the SQL database that contains new meta-data fields used by Azure Storage. A new mobile service SQL insert script asks Azure Storage for a Shared Access Signature (SAS). That script returns the SAS and a URI for the blob to the client. The client uploads the photo, using the SAS and blob URI.

So what is a SAS?

It's not safe to store the credentials needed to upload data to the Azure Storage service inside your client app. Instead, you store these credentials in your mobile service and use them to generate a Shared Access Signature (SAS) that grants permission to upload a new image. The SAS, a credential with a 5 minute expiration, is returned securely by Mobile Services to the client app. The app then uses this temporary credential to upload the image.

for further queries and detail analysis. Visit this official documentation https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-android-upload-data-blob-storage/